# Using Curry Function in JS

Tags: javascript

Working on [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/), I saw the `curry` function.

```
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
      return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
  };
```

Then I tried to use it by currying the `split` function (which inherited it through the `Function.prototype.curry` definition.

```
var splitIt = String.prototype.split.curry(/,\s*/); // split string into array
var results = splitIt("Mugan, Jin, Fuu");
console.log("results", results);
```

But `[]` prints out for the results. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/2KCP8/

Comment: What does `curry` do? (I mean, besides giving flavor to the food XD)

Comment: Think about what currying does: it binds the first n parameters to specific values. You can still pass values for the remaining parameters when you call the curried function. In your case, you treat split as if it accepted two arguments: a delimiter and the string to act upon. That's not how split works though: it only accepts one argument, the delimiter, and the string it applies to is accessed via "this", the context.

Comment: @guill: google function currying

Comment: Thanks, Felix. As I understand `currying` in JavaScript, it means pre-populating function arguments `eagerly`. However, in Scala/Haskell, currying means `lazily` applying arguments to a function.

Comment: Actually that method does not curry a function, it does partially apply it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application for the difference. @KevinMeredith: Currying has nothing to do with lazy evaluation. In Haskell it just is lazy because everything is lazy…

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi. After reading that wiki page, I see that `curry` seems to be a poor name for the above function since it's a partially applied function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "splitIt" function still expects that `this` will refer to the string to be split. You haven't arranged for that to be the case here.

Try

```
var results = splitIt.call("Mugan, Jin, Fuu");
```

Comment: a.k.a `"Mugan, Jin, Fuu".splitIt()`.  Currying here turned a one-argument function into a zero-argument function (ignoring the fact that `this` is an implicit argument).

Comment: I added a `console.log(this)` to the `curry` function. When I called `split(string)`, I saw `this = window`. However, with `splitIt.call(string)`, it equaled the String.

Comment: @KevinMeredith yes that's the expected behavior. If `this` isn't provided with the method of making the function call, it defaults to the global context. In "strict" mode it'd be `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy - so harpo's answer will implicitly `apply` `splitIt` to the string argument? Whereas your answer will explicitly `apply` the function to the arguments?

Comment: @KevinMeredith yes, that's right. (Well, technically the string is boxed with a String object implicitly, and then *that* is used as the value of `this`. But that's an invisible detail.)

Comment: `var results = splitIt.apply("Mugan, Jin, Fuu");` also works. But, I suppose this is obvious since `call` and `apply` are similar except that `call` takes a 2nd argument of `n` arguments (comma-delimited), but `apply` takes a 2nd array argument. Since there is not 2nd argument to `call` or `apply`, they're equivalent here.